# Passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast. What is a cast?

Tags: c

I am new to coding in the C language. I am trying to make a program that detects when the RobloxPlayerBeta.exe is being run, but upon compiling it says that "passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast".
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int logout();
char retrieve();
int main(){
    char value;
    while(1){
        system("cmd.exe /C tasklist > Tasks.txt");
        value = retrieve();
        printf("%d\n",value);
        int thing;
        thing = strcmp(value,"1");
        printf("%d",thing);
        if (thing == 0){
            int x = logout();
        }
        sleep(10);
    }
    return 0;
}

int logout(){
    system("c:\\windows\\system32\\shutdown /l");
    return 0;
}

char retrieve(){
    system("cmd.exe /C start C:\\Users\\chall\\Documents\\Ccode\\Logout\\dist\\FindTask\\FindTask.exe");
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("Tasks.txt","r");
    int number = fgetc(f);
    return number;
}
```

FindTask.exe is an exe made with the following python code:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\chall\Documents\Ccode\Logout\Tasks.txt","r") as db:
    dataset = db.readlines()
    for data in dataset:
        if(data[:20].strip().lower() == "robloxplayerbeta.exe"):
            with open("Tasks.txt","w") as f:
                f.write("1")
```

I would like to know what a cast is and why I need one.

Comment: `strcmp` requires string parameters not a single `char`. Use `if (value == '1')` instead to compare chars.

Comment: You don't need one. You shouldn't be using `strcmp` here. But if you don't know what a cast even is, you need to learn a lot more from your class, tutorial, etc.; we can't teach you C from scratch a question at a time.

Comment: `char value; ...strcmp(value,"1");` --> `strcmp()` expects 2 `char *`.  `value` is not a `char *`, but a `char`.

Comment: `cast` _example_:  `int a;`  `double b = 13.5;`  `a = (int)b`  _(int)_ is the cast.  In this case, it is casting a `double` to look like an `int`.  Typically a cast is a way to tell the compiler _"yes, I know I am assigning the value of one type, to that of another, please don't complain"_.

Comment: Why do you declare `retrieve` as returning `char` but return `int number`? You also leak file handles in `retrieve`, as you fail to close the file after using it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, Ken. That was my bad. And so casting is just changing the data type?

Comment: See [What is typecasting in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4302190/62576)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typecasting in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302190/typecasting-in-c)

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast is to tell the system convert data of one type to another type.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 10;
    double b = (double)a; /* cast is used here */
    printf("%f\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

In this case you don't need cast. `strcmp()` is for compareing strings. You should use operators to deal with numbers to compare single character.

Wrong:

```
        thing = strcmp(value,"1");
```

Correct:

```
        thing = value - '1';
```

Comment: `thing = value - '1';` is an unclear subtraction/comparison.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Do you prefer `thing = (value > '1' ? 1 : (value < '1' ? -1 : 0));`?

Comment: A comment explaining the subtraction would help.  Or as code later uses `if (thing == 0){`,  `thing = value != '1';` would be sufficient.

Comment: I think what @chux is saying is that you should explain why you're subtracting `1` from `value` before assigning it to `thing` and what that line of code does, especially as the OP seems to be rather new to the language.